# Something has taken over Little Snitch?

Tags: security, ssh, launchd, firewall, kernel-extensions

Due to sad neglect, I own the computer from the exorcist.  I finally looked last night and there were 80 sshd connections from China.  I blocked all traffic to/from sshd, and now that sshd is linked to launchd, I blocked all traffic there, too.  Every time I disallow all traffic to/from launchd, it is immediately allowed again, talking to 121 servers.

Apparently something has taken over Little Snitch?  Since Little Snitch installs a kext, what are the implications of this?  How bad is this and what can be done?

Comment: Wipe and re-install your OS.  There's no way to gauge the extent of what has been compromised.

Comment: Please add screenshots of your rules list and net monitor expanded but filtered for sshd!

Comment: Remember that Little Snitch only stops *outgoing* traffic. Blocking traffic in Little Snitch has no effect on **incoming** traffic, that is done with the firewall. @Allen is right, your best bet is to boot into recovery mode, reformat the drive and install masOS from scratch.

Comment: it has options to block both incoming and outgoing traffic

Comment: I agree with Steve and Allan here. Best course of action is to wipe clean, reinstall the OS. Nothing else can help you if they have done something to the OS or your files. Furthermore, I reccomend that you turn on the firewall on your router and block port 22 as it is what runs ssh typically.